# How to send attachment in a mail via workflow

Tags: apex, email, workflow, attachment

Is it possible to send attachment using workflow.If yes let me know how shall it be implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this provided your email template is a visualforce email template.

The visualforce guide has a sample reference on as approach

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_email_templates_attachments.htm